# New file not showing up in git status

Tags: git

I have forked and cloned a repository in order to contribute to it. On the command line I created a new branch, and created a file called 'ansible.cfg', but it doesn't show up when running `git status`. After playing around even a file 'a.cfg' doesn't show up in git status:

```
$ git status
On branch add-selenium-grid
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ touch tests/ui/a.txt tests/ui/a.cfg
$ git status
On branch add-selenium-grid
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    tests/ui/a.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ ls tests/ui/a.*
tests/ui/a.cfg  tests/ui/a.txt
```

I'm pretty new to git, but this seems so basic, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Check .gitignore file, look if there's a line with *.cfg

Comment: There is no *.cfg in .gitignore. Plus, I just tried a `touch a.cfg` and that shows up in git status, but `tests/ui/a.cfg` does not show up in status.

Comment: Try `git check-ignore -v tests/ui/a.cfg` to see what's making it shut up about `a.cfg` (if your Git is not too old to have `check-ignore -v` anyway).

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ?  If so you may want to check the 'Preferences->Version Control->Ignored Files/Ignore Files Support'.

Comment: Hey @torek, that helped. It showed that there is a `tests/ui/.gitignore` file with a *.cfg line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the file or files with this extension are ignored by the git repository because of the `.gitignore` file. In this case it would not appear within `git status`

You can check the content of `.gitignore` with:

```
cat .gitignore
```

[Further details regarding gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: If its not the `.gitignore` file, could you give us the link to your fork so that we can investigate it?